# clarification on take method of LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, and some threads that operate on it.

```
 public void run(){
     ...
      foo(linkedBlockingQueue.take());
     ...
   }

    public void foo(Object o){
       synchronized(o){
              //operate on the object
              ....
              //after operate re-insert the object inside the queue
       }
    }
```

if i have this situation:

*a blocking queue with 5 elements and the "luckiest" thread have gained the control of the first element so:*

- other threads that concurrently wanted the first element will put in `wait`?.
- it is useless to use a `synchronized` block if the first sentence is right?
- other threads can access other positions on the interval when pickup the first element and insertion of this one without `mutex exclusion`?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a blocking queue with 5 elements and the "luckiest" thread have gained
>   the control of the first element so:
>
> ```
> other threads that concurrently wanted the first element will put in wait?.
> ```

No, the other threads will get second, third and so on element until the queue is empty. Only in this case they will block.

> ```
> it is useless to use a synchronized block if the first sentence is right?
> ```

The answer to this has nothing to do with answer to first question. If you process the taken object in a single thread or is immutable, then yes, synchronization is not needed, but you might need it otherwise.

> other threads can access other positions on the interval when pickup 
>   the first element and insertion of this one without mutex
>   exclusion?

You are asking if other threads might get more elements from the queue until the first one is re-added? Yes, the queue is not locked, it can be accessed from other threads.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i understood now.The take method is atomic,naturally, but doesn't block the other threads to get other elements